# Как в Angular очистить кеш?

Tags: angular

Использую Angular 7 после изменения кода в компоненте  вид не изменяется

думаю  это связано с кешом.

Как удалить кеш в  Angular ?

Comment: это никак не связано с кешем) возможно с вашей иде, что вы используете?

Comment: иногда webpack глючит - можно попробовать перезапустить. но более вероятно что ты просто меняешь не тот файл (неиспользуемый, например).

Comment: @Qwertiy, не совсем, это известная проблема, которая встречается в vscode, поэтому  и нужно уточнить какую иде использует автор

Comment: @overthesanity, не верю, что от ide что-то зависит. Или ты про ситуацию, когда в vscode дважды открывается один файл, в обоих вкладках правится, а потом нажимается save all?

Comment: @Qwertiy, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2389#issuecomment-278298718, возможно и не связано с иде :))

Comment: @overthesanity, полмиллиона наблюдаемых файлов? Это что ж за проект такой??

Comment: Ошибка была связано с вебпаком разрешилась само собой

Comment: Это ваш браузер кэш не чистит (если дело именно в нем).

Comment: вы читали комментарии? `Ошибка была связано с вебпаком разрешилась само собой – Gr Brainstorm`